# Create view in load view and set it's frame, but frame auto changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

Why the frame of the view auto changed?

see this codes:

```
- (void)loadView{
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10,0,340,480)];
    self.view = sv;
    NSLog(@"sv frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view))
}

- (void)viewWillAppear{
  NSLog(@"view frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view));
}
```

In my demo
Output :
sv frame = {{-10, 0}, {340, 480}}

view frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}

It should be: view frame = {{-10, 0}, {340, 480}}

But in PhotoScroller demo (2010 WWDC 104), it's correct. It's so strange.

Answer (score 2):

Change both of the methods this way:

```
- (void)loadView{
   UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   self.view = sv;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(-10,0,340,480);
}
```

EDIT: Geometry MUST be set in at least `viewWillAppear:` and later on `UIViewController`'s event lifecycle. Autoresizing masks also can change the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)loadView
{    
    UISCrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view = scrollView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
- (void)loadView{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10,0,340,480)];
    [view addSubview:sv];
    sv.autoresizingMak=UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight;
    self.view = view;
}
```